# Using python and pandas to create combinations instead of permutations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset structurally similar to the one created below. Imagine each `user` brought a bag with the corresponding `fruit`. I want to count all pairwise combinations (not permutations) of `fruit` options, and use them to generate a probability that a `user` owns the bag after pulling two `fruits` out of it. There is an assumption that no `user` ever brings two of the same `fruit`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['Matt', 'Matt', 'Matt', 'Matt', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick'], 'fruit': ['Plum', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Grape', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Tomato']})[['user', 'fruit']]
print df
```

My thought was to merge the dataframe back onto itself on `user`, and generate counts based on unique pairs of `fruit_x` and `fruit_y`.

```
df_merged = df.merge(df, how='inner', on='user')
print df_merged
```

Unfortunately the merge yields two types of unwanted results. Instances where a `fruit` has been merged back onto itself are easy to fix.

```
df_fix1 = df_merged.query('fruit_x != fruit_y')
gb_pair_user = df_fix1.groupby(['user', 'fruit_x', 'fruit_y'])
df_fix1['pair_user_count'] = gb_pair_user['user'].transform('count')
gb_pair = df_fix1.groupby(['fruit_x', 'fruit_y'])
df_fix1['pair_count'] = gb_pair['user'].transform('count')
df_fix1['probability'] = df_fix1['pair_user_count'] / df_fix1['pair_count'] *1.0
print df_fix1[['fruit_x', 'fruit_y', 'probability', 'user']]
```

The second type is where I'm stuck. There is no meaningful difference between `Apple`+`Orange` and `Orange`+`Apple`, so I'd like to remove one of those rows. If there is a way to get proper combinations, I'd be very interested in that, otherwise if anyone can suggest a hack to eliminate the duplicated information that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the advantage of `combinations` from `itertools` to create unique pair of combination of fruits for each user.

```
from itertools import combinations

def func(group): 
    return pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(group.fruit, 2)), columns=['fruit_x', 'fruit_y'])

df.groupby('user').apply(func).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

     fruit_x fruit_y
user                
Matt    Plum   Apple
Matt    Plum  Orange
Matt    Plum    Pear
Matt   Apple  Orange
Matt   Apple    Pear
Matt  Orange    Pear
Nick  Orange   Grape
Nick  Orange   Apple
Nick  Orange  Banana
Nick  Orange  Tomato
Nick   Grape   Apple
Nick   Grape  Banana
Nick   Grape  Tomato
Nick   Apple  Banana
Nick   Apple  Tomato
Nick  Banana  Tomato
Tom    Grape   Apple
Tom    Grape  Orange
Tom    Grape  Banana
Tom    Apple  Orange
Tom    Apple  Banana
Tom   Orange  Banana
```

You can then calculate the probability according to your program logic.